# jQuery | Submit Form with Span

Tags: jquery

I'm wanting to have the span within my form have the same "submit" behaviour as the `input type="submit"`.

Please note I cannot use **AJAX** for this as the third party provider does not support an **AJAX** submission hence there being an `input type="submit"`

Most searches return using the `submit()` method however, this doesn't work?

[JSFIDDLE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/752au7Lv/3/)

**HTML**

```
<form method="post" action="http://www.google.com">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Name">
    <span class="submit-span">Span submit</span>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var spanSubmit = $('.submit-span');

    spanSubmit.on('click', function() {
        $(this).submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Could you just hide your <input type="submit" id="sb"> with CSS and then link your $('span).on('click') to the $('#sb').click()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `$(this)` in your jQuery code is not referring to the form, but the `<span>` element itself. Therefore, you can use DOM transversal to seek/search for the parent `<form>` element:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var spanSubmit = $('.submit-span');

    spanSubmit.on('click', function() {
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
        // Will also work, but might fail if nesting is changed:
        // $(this).parent().submit();
    });
});
```

Here's a [proof-of-concept fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/752au7Lv/4/), where I used an alert to listen to the submit event to verify that form submission is indeed called :)

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you submit the form element in the click handler?

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var spanSubmit = $('.submit-span');

    spanSubmit.on('click', function() {
        $(this).closest('form').submit();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you are calling the submit event on the span (which doesn't have such an event.

```
spanSubmit.on('click', function() {
  $(this).submit();
});
```

You need to call this event on the form:

```
spanSubmit.on('click', function() {
  $(this).closest('form').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You should trigger the native JavaScript `submit` event on the `form` element:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var spanSubmit = $('.submit-span');

    spanSubmit.on('click', function() {
        $(this).closest('form')[0].submit();
    });
});
```